# confusion on auto reference

Tags: c++, reference, auto

I am trying to understand the details of using auto as a reference.

However, I am a bit confused after executing the basic code below.

```
int x = 99;
    
const int& xr = x;
   
auto& xr2 = xr ;
xr2 = 88;
```

I have read that the auto keyword in C++ can eliminate the const and reference qualifiers, so I expected the type of xr2 to be int&. However, I received an error message that said "error: assignment of read-only reference xr2."  Could you please explain why is that?

Best regards.

Comment: `xr` is a const reference, adding more levels of indierection does not change that.

Comment: Whatever you read you probably misunderstood, auto can't be used like const_cast.

Answer (score 3):

`auto xr2 = xr;` would always be non-const non-reference, yes.

But when you add `&`, it no longer strips constness, and is always an (lvalue) reference.

Comment: Also, just for the OP's clarification, because `xr` is a `const &`, the type of `xr2` will also be a `const &`, which is why you cannot assign to it. `auto` follows the exact same rules of type deduction as templates.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for `auto` are fairly simple, because they mirror the rules of function template argument deduction:

> If the *placeholder-type-specifier* is of the form *type-constraint*<sub>opt</sub> `auto`, the deduced type `T'` replacing `T` is determined using the rules for template argument deduction.
>
> [...]
>
> *[Example 2:*
>
> ```cpp
> const auto &i = expr;
> ```
>
> The type of `i` is the deduced type of the parameter `u` in the call
> `f(expr)` of the following invented function template:
>
> ```cpp
> template <class U> void f(const U& u);
> ```
>
> *-- end example]*

- http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#3

#### *Decay* - when `auto` removes cv-qualifiers

The `auto` keyword isn't always allowed to remove cv-qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`); only when declaring a variable as a non-reference. For example:

```cpp
const volatile int& x = ...;
// y is of type int, with no cv-qualifiers
auto y = x;
```

This is because cv-qualifiers are dropped when passing to non-reference function parameters (this is called *decay*).
`auto` variables follow the rules of function template argument deduction, so the same thing happens here.

#### Why your example doesn't compile

In your example, all uses of `auto` still involve `&`, so no decay takes place, and cv-qualifiers are preserved.
Your code doesn't compile because the following happens:

```cpp
int x = 99;

const int& xr = x;

// auto deduces to const int
// xr2 is declared as const int&, just like xr
auto& xr2 = xr ;
// error: assigning 88 to const variable
xr2 = 88;
```